# Insert element in list ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I created a function that insert one element in a list.

The insertion will happens when the element `i` is equal to `k`.

The list is a list of `(int * string) list` , like `[(1,"hi")...]`
The idea is to create a new list where for each iteration `hd` is append at the beginning.
When `i` is found then `k` is inserted and the function stops.
Here the code :

```
let rec insert k v list_ = 
 let rec support k v list _
  match list_ with
  | (i,value) when i = k -> (k,v) :: tl
  | hd :: [] -> hd
  | hd :: tl -> hd :: support k v tl in 
 let inserted = support k v list_

let () =
  let k = [ (1,"ciao");(2,"Hola");(3,"Salut") ] in
  insert 2 "Aufwidersen" k
```

I think all is fine but the compiler said :

```
5 | | hd :: [] -> hd
Error: This pattern matches values of type 'a list
   but a pattern was expected which matches values of type 'b * 'c`
```

And I don't understand why, I think all is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this part:

```
match list_ with
  | (i,value) -> ...
```

When you write this, Ocaml infers that `list_` has to be a tuple, which is a type error because it is actually a list of tuples.

I didn't understand exactly what you want the insert function but the typical pattern is to have two cases, one for the empty list and one for the non-empty list. I personally prefer using if-then-else instead of pattern guards but if you want to use pattern guards that should also work. Either way, you certainly want to cover the case of the empty list.

```
match list_ with
| [] -> (* ... *)
| (i,value)::tl -> 
    if i = k then
       (* ... *)
    else
       (* ... *)
```

Comment: It works thank you! What I want to do is create a new list with (2,"aufwidersen") instead of (2,"Hola"), but I have a little problem because the return of this function is unit. It should be (int * string ) list. Because "let inserted = support k v list_" isn't seen as return, I guess.